# Android 11-12 problem with bluetooth send and get data

Tags: android, bluetooth

On android 12 and 11 I have a problem with send data and get data from and to device this is what I do :

For send to device

```
public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytes;
    while (true) {
        try {
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionLost();
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void write(byte[] buffer) {

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

I use my application to pair with device and I am correct paired with device

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan my phone do not get response from another device

Comment: If you have exceptions then tell and post the stacktrace.